# How to loop for multiple columns in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have this below code to copy data from one sheet and to paste it onto another sheet. However, i need to paste about 100 columns of data. How do i get my loop to run 100 times so i dont have to copy this code down a 100 times?

Thanks

```
Sub Macro1()

    Dim lastrow as long, erow as long

    lastrow = Sheet4.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 to lastrow
        Sheets4.cells(i,1).Copy
        erow = Sheet7.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Row

        Sheet4.Paste Sheet7.Cells(erow,1)

        Sheet4.Cells(i,2).Copy
        Sheet4.Paste Sheet7.Cells(erow,2)
```

Comment: You have a `for loop` for rows.  You can nest another `for loop` for columns.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are copying cell by cell in a loop... just copy the entire range at once?

Comment: Do you need to skip some columns/rows? Do you need to paste Format, also?

Comment: @BigBen, how do i copy the entire range at once. I am new to VBA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not say anything and I cannot stay, anymore... If you do not need to copy format, try the next code. It will copy all columns of `Sheet4` starting from their second row, to the first empty row of `Shee77`. It is much faster than what you tried, using an array and drop all content at once...

```
Sub Macro1_bis()
 Dim arrSh4 As Variant, sh7Row As Long
 arrSh4 = Sheet4.UsedRange.Offset(1).value
 sh7Row = Sheet7.Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
 Sheet7.Range("A" & sh7Row).Resize(UBound(arrSh4, 1), UBound(arrSh4, 2)).value = arrSh4
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, this code is not working. I am unsure of the issue

Comment: @user13078770: "Do you need to skip some columns/rows? Do you need to paste Format, also? " This is my pending question for you... My code should copy all used range of Sheet4, starting from the second row, in the first empty row of Sheet7, If this is not what you like it to do, can you better explain what do you need? In terms of final result...

Comment: I do not need to skip any columns or rows (do need to start pasting data into row 2). I need to copy all of the data in column a and once i get to the end of that column i need to move to column b etc. i do not need any specific formatting either.

Comment: This way is what you thought. But did you correctly define your sheets before running the code? Do you receive a message? If yes, what and of which row? Is not, the code works well, but on wrong sheets...

Comment: when i run it, nothing happens

Comment: Dumb me, made a syntax mistake. Thank you so much. It works!

Comment: @user13078770: Glad to here theat! If it works as you need. It would be good to tick the  left code side  check box, in order to make it accepted answer. If somebody will search for something similar, he will find it faster...

Comment: How would i alter that code to only select certain columns? Say i want all of the rows with data, but only want columns A,B, H, I, and M?

Comment: This would be a little more complicated, but not impossible. You cannot build an array able to skip columns. If you would try that, the empty columns will rewrite the existing values when drop the content, if exists. So, the solution will involve three arrays: One for the first two (adjacent) columns and other two for the next two (non adjacent) columns... And you can drop the array content in whatever range of the target sheet you want.

Comment: Would i have to use arrays or could i do something else?